# Glassfish, problem obtaining EJB through JNDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi

I am trying to obtain a reference to EJB2 from EJB1. EJB2 is deployed separately, but they are both running in the same container. I'm using the following code in EJB1:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
Connector connector = (Connector) ctx.lookup("java:global/earFile/ejbArtifact/EJB2")
```

`Connector` is an interface which is packaged with EJB1. It is implemented by EJB2.

The above snippet will give me following exception message:

```
$Proxy283 cannot be cast to Connector
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you do this?

    System.out.println( ctx.lookup(...).getClass().getName() );

Comment: It showed `$Proxy283`. But I figured it out, I'll post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `Connector` interface had to be annotated as `@Local` interface. Now it works.